# Puppeteer - How can I know if spinner is moving

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

As the title says how can i know if the page spinner is moving?

I know that you can do this:
`await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});`
to ensure the spinner completely stops.

But I would like to know if the spinner is even moving first.

So in psuedo code, I'm trying to achieve something like this

```
if (spinnerIsMoving == true){
  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
}
else{  
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: Which spinner are refering too, Denise?

Comment: @Vaviloff The spinner at the top left of your browser. indicating if the page is loading or not haha